# divide large string into smaller chunks and count each chunk php?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, symfony1

i want divide large string into smaller chunks and count occurrence of each chunk in database

[image]

example:

```
###Windows###Apple###Android
```

now i want count occurrence of Windows ,Apple,Android in column "answer" all database.

Strings in answer column may not be fixed all time it will depend on answer!

Comment: Is there any reliable way to divide the text into chunks? Like each word gets separated with some ###?

Comment: looks lie you should normalise the data

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with this rather inefficient method:

```
select v.val, count(*)
from (select 'Windows' as val union all
      select 'Apple' union all
      select 'Android'
     ) v join
     table t
     on t.answer like concat('%', v.val, '%')
group by v.val;
```

Comment: thanks Gordon !but values in answer column may not be fixed all time it will depend on answer!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't clearly understand your problem but if I am correct you want something like this.

First you have to query your database to get the answer column, then after that you have to put the answer in a string. Then use `substr_count`.Something like this.

```
<?php
$text = '###Windows###Apple###Android';
echo substr_count($text, 'Windows'); 
?>
```

Hope this is what you are looking.